# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host <ip>: bundle exit status: 18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, sidekiq, capistrano3

These are the error i get in the console

`INFO[1bc8ff9e] Running /usr/bin/env sudo /usr/bin/monit unmonitor sidekiq_app_production0 on <ip>
    DEBUG[1bc8ff9e] Command: /usr/bin/env sudo /usr/bin/monit unmonitor sidekiq_app_production0
    DEBUG[1bc8ff9e]     sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
    UG[1bc8ff9e]    sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

I am using the following capistrano gems

`gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
    gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
    gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have the privileges to do sudo at server and check the user exists!

Comment: The script was working before, we used to deploy it using this method. If not is there anything in particular i can have a look it so as to check if the user doesn't have the permission.